# Regex to find number followed by exact string match

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string. Let's say "This response happened in 90ms. Response finished".

I need to be able to parse out the "90ms" from the string.

The regex needs to match against an arbitrary number of numbers followed by an exact string match, in this case the string would be "ms".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try this regex?

```
\d+ms
```

`\d+` - matches one or more digits.

`ms` - Matches the string `ms`

**Example:**

```
> "This response happened in 90ms. Response finished".match(/\d+ms/)[0];
'90ms'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp:

```
\d+ms
```

`\d` matches a digit, `+` means to match 1 or more of them, and `ms` matches that exact string.

Now I suggest you go read a tutorial on regular expressions, there's one at regular-expressions.info. This is about as basic as it gets, so if you need to ask about things like this you'll be here every day, getting us to write your code one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the expression you need to use this:

```
var rx = /(\d+ms)/;
var arr = rx.exec(your_string);
extracted= arr[1];
```

The extracted string is what is between parenthesis. If you need only the number change de rx to /(\d+)ms/.

Comment: You don't need a capture group if it's the entire regexp. The match for the regexp will be in `arr[0]`.

Comment: @Barmar, You are right. The group is only needed in the case the OP needs just the number.